# Retrieving and Storing images in SQLite in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, sqlite

How can we create a button to store and retrieve images in sqlite in ios application?
Actually I am building a Application in which i can take photo from camera and I have to store it and display as a profile picture

Comment: you can try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349350/storing-and-retrieving-image-from-sqlite-database-in-ios/33543791#33543791

Comment: wait.... [take a look at SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) using this lib, you just provide the URL of the photo and it will do the job of caching...

Answer (score 2):

Storing image data in database is not proper way if you want to store large number of images. It will hang the UI.

You can make a folder in Document Directory and put the image there. So, you will get image from there only every time.

In the database, store the file-path and get the image from that file path.

**Be sure to remove the images from Document Directory, once it becomes unusable i.e. user changes the profile picture. Otherwise, it will continuously increase your App's memory.**

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html See "File archives" and "Replacement for ad hoc disk files."

Answer (score 0):

Better to store the image at file path which is your document directory and store the file path in sqlite for faster access of the image.

Make a file path as below:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory 
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

Now filepath string will insert into your sqlite database.

and now when you access the image you will get file path from the sqlite and get image data from that like below:

```
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
```

Comment: Why is it better? This is a perfect use case for SQLite, playing up its strengths.

Comment: @StevenFisher It's not the most efficient way to store them though. Databases aren't meant for storing information in the format of an image. So, the short slightly simplified answer is its a performance nightmare with too much overhead.

Comment: It's hardly a performance nightmare, and it's reasonably efficient. This is one of the stated use cases of SQLite, in fact. Don't get me wrong, for any other database you'd be absolutely correct. But SQLite is more a replacement for fopen than for a traditional database.